# Unable to access Spark nodes in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-spark

I am using this setup (https://github.com/mvillarrealb/docker-spark-cluster.git) to established a Spark Cluster but none of the IPs mentioned there like `10.5.0.2` area accessible via browser and giving timeout. I am unable to figure out what's wrong am I doing?

I am using Docker 2.3 on macOS Catalina.

In the `spark-base` Dockerfile I am using the following settings instead of one given there:

```
ENV DAEMON_RUN=true
ENV SPARK_VERSION=3.0.0
ENV HADOOP_VERSION=3.2
ENV SCALA_VERSION=2.12.4
ENV SCALA_HOME=/usr/share/scala
ENV SPARK_HOME=/spark
```

Also when running, it still shows Spark 2.4.3 on the console when trying to run web UI.

Comment: Can you quick check? Try to access localhost:9090 or localhost:7077 in your browser. I can explain if this works

Comment: @NeoAnderson `9090` with localhost working from the browser but not 7077. I can also see worker Ids. `http://localhost:8081/` also not working.

Comment: That's fine. localhost:9090 is the one that's supposed to be accessed from the browser. :7077 is not http.

Comment: @NeoAnderson how can I access WebUI of workers? I attached a shell with one of the worker containers and ran `curl http://952af8511386:8081` and it returned the HTML. From Host I am unable to access.

Comment: I need to have a look in the compose file. I guess you need to publish(expose) some ports outside the 10.x.x.x network

Comment: this is what I am talking about: https://github.com/mvillarrealb/docker-spark-cluster/blob/efd056a61ebc3e22e04941baaf1c2c1c296c30f9/docker-compose.yml#L6

Comment: Only the master is configured to expose 9090 outside the 10.x.x.x network on your host machine. If you want to do the same for the workers, you need to change that dockerfile

Comment: @NeoAnderson Worker `Dockerfile` already expose 8081 yet I can't use it: https://github.com/mvillarrealb/docker-spark-cluster/blob/master/docker/spark-worker/Dockerfile

Comment: reply in answer for better formatting. A random port will be chosen on the host machine, to be forwarded to the 8081 on each worker. In theory you could chose that port, but if you have more than one worker, of course you would have a port conflict

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218367/discussion-between-neo-anderson-and-volatil3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dockerfile tells the container what port to expose.
The compose-file tells the host which ports to expose and to which ports should be the traffic forwarded inside the container.
If the source port is not specified, a random port should be generated. This statement helps in this scenario because you have multiple workers and you cannot specify a unique source port for all of them - this would result in a conflict.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  spark-master:
    image: spydernaz/spark-master:latest
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
       - ./apps:/opt/spark-apps
       - ./data:/opt/spark-data
    environment:
      - "SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-master"
  spark-worker:
    image: spydernaz/spark-worker:latest
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=128m
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=256m
    volumes:
       - ./apps:/opt/spark-apps
       - ./data:/opt/spark-data
```

To find the randomly generated published port for each of the workers, run `docker ps`. Under the column PORTS you should find what you need:

```
PORTS 
0.0.0.0:32768->8080/tcp
```

`32768` will forward from the host machine (`localhost:32768`) to the `[worker-IP]:8080`